# Division between two annotations

Tags: django

I'm creating those two annotations as it follows:

```
cs = Champion.objects.all()

total_games = Match.objects.all().count()

cs = cs.annotate(
    picked_games=Count(
        expression='participants__match__id',
        filter=Q(participants__role='BOTTOM'),
        distinct=True
    ),
    total_games=Value(str(total_games), output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

And everthing's alright until here. I fetch both the `picked_games` and `total_games` with correct results.

```
>>> cs.get(name='Jhin').picked_games
27544
>>> cs.get(name='Jhin').total_games
97410
```

However, if i try to divide one by another:

```
cs = cs.annotate(
    pick_rate=ExpressionWrapper(
        expression=F('picked_games') / F('total_games'),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

This results on a 0:

```
>>> cs.get(name='Jhin').pick_rate
0.0
```

I don't understand what's problem here..

I can get the result if divide them externally, so why can't i get the result on a different column for the whole queryset?

```
>>> cs.get(name='Jhin').picked_games / cs.get(name='Jhin').total_games
0.28319474386613286
```

Comment: Do you use a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: How did you guess it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast the numerator (or denominator) to a float *before* making the division, otherwise the PostgreSQL database will use *integer division* and thus truncate towards zero. You thus can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, FloatField, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

total_games = Match.objects.all().count()

Champion.objects.annotate(
    picked_games=Count(
        expression='participants__match__id',
        filter=Q(participants__role='BOTTOM'),
        distinct=True
    )
).annotate(
    pick_rate=Cast('picked_games', output_field=FloatField()) / total_games
)
```